# Devise touch session (prevent timeout)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, session-timeout

I'm using Devise `timeoutable` to time out user sessions, and am trying to use client-side AJAX calls to occasionally touch the user session and keep the session alive.  However, the server-side call in my subclass of `Devise::SessionsController` is not actually "touching" the session and preventing timeout:

```
def touch
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {head :bad_request}
    format.js {
      render :json => { :session_expires => User.timeout_in.to_i}, :status => :ok
    }
    format.json {
      render :json => { :session_expires => User.timeout_in.to_i}, :status => :ok
    }
  end
end
```

What do I need to do to actually cause some session activity and prevent the timeout from triggering?

Comment: Have you found a solution by now?

Comment: I imagine I did, but it's been long enough that I don't remember it.